# My question is deleted; how do I read the answers?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

I've posted a question that is now deleted, but before it was deleted it had 4 answers. (I know this through the stack-exchange-bar at the top left corner.)

When i click the link to the question (from my inbox in stackexchange) i reached https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76162/why-is-google-giving-people-money-to-switch-to-firefox-and-not-switch-to-google-c

I want to be able to read those replies. What should I do?

Comment: Do you know why it was deleted - as a duplicate, or something else? If it was a duplicate then there's probably another question you can read instead.

Comment: Which was the question you are referring to?

Comment: @Rup Duplicate questions are closed, not deleted. They will get eventually deleted, later.

Comment: @kiamlaluno My question was why Google is encouraging people to use Firefox instead of Google chrome. there's a link provided in that question (my source) which i can't rmb now

Comment: @Rup nop. how can i know? is there a page i can check for this kind of things?

Comment: @Pacerier The popup you are referring to reports also the number of comments you got on your questions/answers. It could be your question had 4 comments, and not 4 answers.

Comment: If you click on one of the links in your inbox then you'll get the deleted question page. There should (hopefully) be a reason at the top of the page - "this page was deleted because XYZ"

Comment: @Rup nop there isn't one. link from inbox: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/76162/why-is-google-giving-people-money-to-switch-to-firefox-and-not-switch-to-google-c

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes I'm interested in reading those comments

Comment: Have you tried your [network profile inbox](http://stackexchange.com/users/025e323f-864d-4cb8-8c50-8cf7390a8012?tab=inbox)? That's the large version of your supercollider dropdown. If they're just comments you should get the full text in there. (Or is that what you meant by your inbox in stackexchange?)

Comment: @Rup it shows part of the comments (truncated). but i do wish to see the whole comments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a moderator on Programmers.SE, so I can see the question.

In your question, you posted a link to a known malware site and the answers to the question were completely irredeemable.

It was deleted because it actively made the internet *worse*. So, for the sake of the internet, there's no way to access the question unless you happen to be a moderator or user with 10,000 or more reputation.

Comment: i'd just want to know what they write (not the truncated versions) could you help post those messages here? thx

Comment: @Pacerier the comments were requests to delete the question.