# Why can't i edit my own question?

Tags: support, questions, answers, edits

Hi all, I've got a question at [My question is deleted; how do I read the answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91372/my-question-is-deleted-how-do-i-read-the-answers) and I want to edit the answer.

But i couldn't do so.

[image: screenshot]

To be sure, I'm logged into the account that posted the question.

Comment: It looks like you've succeeded in editing the question.

Comment: Why not? What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[kiamlaluno](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140449/kiamlaluno) had suggested an edit for your question.

When your post has a pending edit, you must approve or reject that edit before you can edit it yourself.

Comment: weird i had never accepted any edits before yet i've had cases when my question is edited by someone else!

Comment: @Pacerior: People with more than 2,000 reputation have full editing privileges, and can also accept arbitrary suggested edits.